# Do we get any benefit from adding null check if we are already using catch all Exception handler?

Tags: c#

This is specific to .NET
I am writing a code piece where I have to use catch all exception handler. I call a series of function which may return null. I do not want to continue if any of them return null as I have an alternate but costly method to get the same result. I want to know if I should be using the series of null checks or not.
My code looks something like:

```
    var some_info = null;
    try{
        var a = GetA();
        if(a != null){
            var b = a.GetB();
            if(b != null){
                var c = GetC(b);
                if(c != null){
                    some_info = c.GetSomeInfo();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            // cant do anything here but I need above code to be silent
        }
    if(some_info == null)
        some_info = GetSomeInfoFromHeavyMethod();
```

in C# if we try to use null reference it throws an exception so if any of the variables above will be null a NullReferenceException will be thrown. Therefore we can write the above code like

```
    var some_info = null;
    try{
            var a = GetA();
            var b = a.GetB();
            var c = GetC(b);
            some_info = c.GetSomeInfo();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            // cant do anything here but I need above code to be silent
        }
    if(some_info == null)
        some_info = GetSomeInfoFromHeavyMethod();
```

My question is, should I use null checks here or let exception handler work here? My gut feeling says I should use the null check as it is good practice but, I have a doubt as I have to use catch all exception handler here and I already have to bear cost of try/catch block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I would strongly advise using null checks:

- It shows that you *expect* that the values can be null, and that that in itself is not a problem
- If you ever add logging in your catch block, you can easily do so without being spammed by easily-avoidable messages
- When debugging the code, you really don't want to end up with the debugger stopping for a `NullReferenceException` due to just not doing checks
- You say that you "already have to bear cost of try/catch block" - it's not clear whether you're talking about the code readability cost or performance cost, but there's basically *no* performance cost for a try/catch block if no exception is thrown. Compare that with the case when an exception *is* thrown, which definitely has performance implications.

Ultimately, I'd consider every `NullReferenceException` to be a bug somewhere - it's the kind of exception that should always cause you to either add more validation (e.g. to throw `ArgumentNullException`) or handle the value being null. That wouldn't the case in your code.

With some refactoring you may be able to use the null-conditional operator introduced in C# 6 to reduce the code though. You might end up with:

```
someInfo = GetA()?.GetB()?.GetC()?.GetSomeInfo();
```

Comment: With cost what I meant was performance cost but, you solved my dilemma . Thanks.

Comment: I too felt the same but, I got confused when I read section about using NullReferenceException in release code in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @M.S.K: That looks like a poorly written bit of documentation, IMO.

Comment: Agreed. One thing I noticed though: "Compare that with the case when an exception is thrown, which definitely has performance implications." -- sure, but checking for `null` also has a performance cost. If it's really, really high performance code and returning null is very, very rare, not having the null checks will give slightly better performance. That said, that's a very rare scenario, so it doesn't affect the answer in any way.

Comment: I got into exact same problem a couple of days ago and I'll disagree with @Jon as the information in this question to take any rational decision in not suffitient. One must understand that following best practices without looking into its rational is cargo cult programming. Here, asker has not mentioned on chances of returning null from these methods. In case they throw other exceptions and very rarely return null he should not use null checks and everyone understand catch all exception handler, what he mean is actually clear.

Comment: @Shubham: *Why* should they not use null checks in that case? Does it not make it clearer that they're expecting possibly-null results, and handling them in a simple way? You talk about not blindly following best practices, but my answer gives reasons - your "he should not use null checks" doesn't give any reasons why you think that's better.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The reason why he should not use null checks (in case the function returns a nullable object but, nulls are rare or almost impossible considering business logic and he is anyways catching NullReferenceException) is it is not required. What I mean is you just don't check null because a function can return null. It will depend on how exceptional it is for your business case. I am more aligned to what the other answer by Mike Nakis says.

Comment: @Shubham: Not all functions I am calling have same frequency of returning null. Also, the function GetA in this example is in fact a factory method in my actual code. GetB is called on a interface reference and I can't comment on its implementation. GetC in my case is a static private function and I can change it the way I want.

Comment: @Shubham: If a method returning null is rare but doesn't indicate a bug, then I would *not* want that to count as "exceptional". If I see a NullReferenceException in a debugger, I'd want to find where the bug is. I would view "well we're going to catch the exception anyway" as laziness. If you're really in the incredibly rare situation where the null checks are a bottleneck, then sure - catch it and put a huge comment explaining that you know you're in a very rare situation and you wouldn't normally do that... but I think that's an incredibly unusual position.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Do you mean one should religiously never catch a NullReferenceException? In C++ things are different though. I am not talking about null check as bottleneck or a very rare condition but, how you want reader to read your code. You wanna say "null here is something unusual" or "Its usual to get null here". As far as catching a this exception is concern if your code is tolerant and can recover, one can log and continue.

Comment: @M.S.K in modern language it is often better to throw meaningful exception then to return null. Expecting a null from factory method depends on the coding practice followed at other places in your code. Check null for GetB if think it is ok for implementation to return null as per your business logic. GetC is your own function if your business logic understands null as an value then return it and if it is an error condition throw a meaningful exception. NullReferenceException are easy to notice in debugger and can be used to mark conditions which you didn't assumed while writing your code.

Comment: @Shubham: The only time I'd explicitly catch `NullReferenceException` if I knew I was calling code that would throw it in a way I couldn't avoid. I'm fine with catching `Exception` as a full catch-all and that including any `NullReferenceException` in that... but I'd log the exception and investigate any `NullReferenceException`. As you yourself say: "NullReferenceException are easy to notice in debugger and can be used to mark conditions which you didn't assumed while writing your code" - so it should be for **a condition you assumed wouldn't occur**.

Comment: @Shubham: Whereas you're saying that it's fine to anticipate that it *might* occur, but you'll just let the exception happen naturally. That's not the same thing at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess we'll keep going on this one. Jet me just summarize my point. 1. I feel null should be checked when it means something to the system otherwise in most of the cases it will denote a bug and decision may differ from place to place. 2. It is not OK to say phrases like "One should always do..." as it will depend on situation to situation. 3. I do understand what you are saying I agree too but, I am trying to question how correct is that. For example you said writing code in one way makes code more readable but, for whom? perspective may differ. cont...

Comment: ... Error checking is a old way of coding Exception is new. Returning null from a function when null doesn't mean anything in the context itself is wrong hence the domain and business logic must be considered before deciding on exceptional cases. Lastly, programmers in other language like Python or Groovy do this kind of coding where they do first and catch the exception.

Comment: @Shubham: I think we'll have to agree to disagree. I won't try to respond to any individual points, as that way this already-too-long-thread will just be perpetuated.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions are supposed to be thrown when exceptional situations occur.  So, it all depends on whether you want to consider the case of a function returning `null` exceptional or not.  There is no hard rule.

Though I would suspect that if the functions are returning `null` instead of throwing an exception, then a certain choice has already been made, by those who implemented those functions, that the situation is *not* exceptional.  But of course at the place where you call these functions you may want to redefine what is exceptional and what isn't.

There is, however, a little technical issue: throwing an exception is extremely know on Microsoft's implementation of C#, (possibly also on Mono? I don't know) so we unfortunately tend to favor *not* considering certain situations exceptional (and therefore *not* throwing an exception) when the choice is borderline *and* performance is an issue.

Comment: Yes that's very true. I recall that unwinding the stack (e.g. e.StackTrace) is the underlying reason why exceptions are so slow in C#; just forcing an interrupt and a context switch isn't really a problem. It's interesting if you compare this with C++ where collecting stack traces isn't the default behavior - it makes a lot of difference on the way people use exceptions.